# jQuery: how to use comma as separator for .each loop

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I am using the following to loop through all fields with a specific class and add their values to a variable. This works fine so far.

What is the best / fastest way to add a comma as a separator between the values in the variable here BUT avoid having a comma at the beginning or the end of the variable's content ?

The content of the variable in the end should look like this: value1,value2,value3, ...

**My function:**

```
var myVariable = '';

$('.myClass').each(function()
{
    myVariable += $(this).val();
})
```

Thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jQuery [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), also use `this.valu`e instead of `$(this).val()`.

```
$('.myClass').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

**Edit** Based on comments

```
var myVariable = $('.myClass').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get().join(',');
```

Comment: This is great - thanks a lot ! I didn't know the map function yet.

Comment: One more question on this: how do i update my variable with the output of this ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var myVariable = [];
$('.myClass').each(function() {
    myVariable.push($(this).val());
});

var commaSepValues = myVariable.join(','); // add commas between the values...
```